# Html CheckBoxFor helper in MVC 4 Razor - Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, checkboxfor

I am trying to render list of checkboxes from an external db table BUT I keep getting this error:  **Cannot implicitely convert type 'int' to 'bool'**.

I am guessing its not happy b/c of my strongly type view which returns a list. Can anyone please help. Thank you in advance.

my model

```
public partial class tblCity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

my view

```
@model List<Demo.Models.Sample>    

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{    
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].ID)  **Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'**
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are giving it an int

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{    
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].ID) <- ID is an Int
}
```

You'd need to give it a bool. Maybe IsSelected was supposed to be a bool, and that was what you were looking for?

```
public partial class tblCity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Then the view

```
@model List<Demo.Models.Sample>    

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{    
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsSelected )
}
```

Comment: Here is the thing. The 'tblCity' model was generated from a third party database/table and I don't have control over the field data-type and the table doesn't not have any field that returns a bool. 

For a @tml.CheckBoxFor() to work does it have to have a bool field or can I simply replace _public int IsSelected { get; set; }_ to _public bool IsSelected { get; set; }_ on my generated model?

Comment: CheckBoxFor has to take a boolean, so if you change the model, that should be fine. As long as the object going in is a boolean.